# what's the biggest and most frequented forum/board for iphone development?

Tags: iphone

I've just enrolled into the program and it's pending. I know there is an top-secret apple forum for enrolled iphone developers, but I wonder if there are any others which are good?

I feel that my problems are too complex and need more discussion that can't be done just in comments.

Answer (score 4):

You found it. Welcome to the biggest and most responsive iPhone programming forum.

Answer (score 3):

If you can avoid it, I wouldnt use the apple iphone forum. Its REALLY slow. I've had better luck this morning finding answers on SO then over 3 days on the iphone boards

Answer (score 3):

I recommend the [iPhoneSDK group on Google](http://groups.google.com/group/iphonesdk?hl=en). It is frequented by experts.

[Apple's members-only forums](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/discussionForum.action) do have useful stuff especially if you want to find out about Beta products that developers are hesitant to discuss elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/ seems to be pretty popular.

Answer (score 1):

A top-secret apple forum .. I'm an iPhone developer, and I've never heard of it, perhaps I'm just not that good :(

Anyway, the apple support discussion forums are adequate (nothing compares to Stackoverflow); http://discussions.apple.com/forum.jspa?forumID=727&start=0

I'd like to see what other forums people read. I usually end up on some blog when I type in a question in Google.

Comment: you mean that they're less frequented regarding iphone than SO?

Comment: Isn't your comment meant for Alex? ;-)